# How to set and change the image in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web page built in asp.net mvc in which I am not sure how to change an image (`which is a square box left to Basic text` marked in the blue circle as shown in the screenshot below) to another image. The code belonging to that image is:

```
cols.Bound(e => e.EleNum)
       .HeaderTemplate("<img id='btnEleExpandCollapse' src='" + @Url.Content("~/images/icon/ec-expand.png") + "' alt=\"" + @rsc_rating_Index.action_criteria_expand + "\" title=\"" + @rsc_rating_Index.action_criteria_expand + "\" class='btnImgNobg tooltip' style='width:30px;height:30px;visibility:visible;' />")
       .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grd-center grd-valign-mdl", @style = "border-left-width:0px;" })
       .ClientTemplate("<img id='imgEleLevel#:EleID#' src='" + @Url.Content("#:EleLevelImageLocation#") + "' alt=\"" + "#:EleLevelText#" + "\" title=\"" + "#:EleLevelText#" + "\" class='tooltip' style='width:24px;height:24px;' />")
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grd-center", @style = "width:40px;" });
```

Attached is the screenshot of the webpage from the above code. I am wondering `how to remove the text Basic and a square box image marked in blue circle`  from the above code?  On inspect, the following line covers the basic text and a square image as shown below.

```
.ClientTemplate("<img id='imgEleLevel#:EleID#' src='" + @Url.Content("#:EleLevelImageLocation#") + "' alt=\"" + "#:EleLevelText#" + "\" title=\"" + "#:EleLevelText#" + "\" class='tooltip' style='width:24px;height:24px;' />")
```

[image]

I have a feeling that the changes need to be done in the following line but I am not sure where exactly and how. Any pointer on that will be highly appreciated.

```
.ClientTemplate("<img id='imgEleLevel#:EleID#' src='" + @Url.Content("#:EleLevelImageLocation#") + "' alt=\"" + "#:EleLevelText#" + "\" title=\"" + "#:EleLevelText#" + "\" class='tooltip' style='width:24px;height:24px;' />")
```

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like Kendoui grid control is being used. You should look for DataSource or data binding to find out  where the value for  EleLevelImageLocation is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
.ClientTemplate("<img id='imgEleLevel#=EleID#' src='" + @Url.Content("#= Proposal_ID #") + "' alt=\"" + "#=EleLevelText#" + "\" title=\"" + "#=EleLevelText#" + "\" class='tooltip' style='width:24px;height:24px;' />")
```

i hope it'll work for you.